# vbox layout with Sencha 5.0

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am complete newbie to GUI and now figuring my way into it with Sencha framework. I have Sencha 5.0 installed and going through couple of examples,

Belwo code is from online example of how to use vbox layouts and I cannot get it to work, I see a blank screen.

```
Ext.application({
 //   requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
    name: 'AY',
    appFolder: 'app',
    launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            fullscreen: true,
            layout:{
               type: 'vbox'
            } ,
            items: [{
                html: 'Top item',
                style: 'background-color: #5E99CC;',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                html: 'Center item',
                height: 100
            }, {
                html: 'Bottom item',
                style: 'background-color: #759E60;',
                flex: 1
            }]
        });
    } // launch
}); // application()
```

I have seen this happen with my other experiments as well, unlike coding in Java there does not seem to be good way to debug these, I can still use log statements, but they dont help me debug why something does not show in browser.

Apreciate any pointers on whats going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `renderTo:Ext.getBody()` to the config of container.

Comment: That really was the problem, the online code [here](http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.0.0/docs/Ext.layout.VBox.2/) does not have that line! Thank you!

Comment: Because you're looking at an example for Sencha Touch. It's not the same as Ext JS. There's no fullscreen option in Ext.